# Using Paper.js in a Vue SSR application

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, paperjs

I'm using a custom-built Vue SSR application that roughly approximates the example in the official guide. I've tried to install paper.js into it, and I get the following errors, which are reproduced in full at [this Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/GzXEGv5g):

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/paper/dist/node/extend.js
48:32-39 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./node_modules/paper/dist/node/canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'canvas' in '/Users/chaseries/Desktop/ANIMATION_FINAL_2/node_modules/paper/dist/node'

WARNING in ./node_modules/paper/dist/node/self.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsdom' in '/Users/chaseries/Desktop/ANIMATION_FINAL_2/node_modules/paper/dist/node'

WARNING in ./node_modules/paper/dist/node/extend.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

ERROR in ./node_modules/paper/dist/node/canvas.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils' in
```

The offending code is just an `import paper from "paper";` statement at the top level of one of my pages. The app doesn't run at all.

Now, this makes sense to me on some level: the server-side code is trying to use paper.js and is failing with unmet dependencies. So I tried to move the import into a conditional on the `mounted` method, as such:

```
...
mounted () {
    let paper;
    if (process.browser) {
        paper = require("paper");
    }
...
}
```

Webpack spits out the same warnings and errors, but it actually compiles and actually works. I've seen a handful of other questions seemingly exactly like this that say to require `"paper/dist/paper-full.js"` rather than just `"paper"`, but that does nothing to silence the warnings and errors for me.

What's going on here? Why is the import being evaluated at all if it's not going to be pre-rendered on the server? I've tried just solving the issue by installing the relevant libraries, but that's a whole 'nother nest of thorns: webpack complains that it cannot evaluate some of the node-specific code, particularly in node-canvas, and all of the solutions I've tried fell flat. (I'd love for this code to be isomorphic, but I'm honestly afraid to jump down that rabbit hole, not knowing enough about webpack, and given the paucity of documentation on running paper.js in node.)

A working example can be found [on my Github](https://github.com/chaseries/stackoverflow-vue-ssr-paper) for debugging purposes.

**Note: if everything compiles fine, open up `./src/page/Index.vue`, re-save it, and the error should appear—this is another weirdness that keeps happening.** Every once in a while on save, webpack spits out pure green and says everything's good, only to freak out on the next save.

Also, contrary to what I've read elsewhere, the problem seems to have nothing to do with webpack itself, because importing `paper` into a client-side only webpack project works no problem.